# OWIN - Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, claims-based-identity

OK, so I have this MVC5 website, using claims identity.

OWIN Throws this nasty error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

If I manually delete everything in the 'bin' and 'obj' folders, the website works.

problem is that I also get this error, from time to time, on the deployment.

SQL Server is fine, working 100%.
It is something else from OWIN, causing this.

I remember I had this issue in the past, but I cannot recall what I did to fix it.

Here's the full Stack Trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +1385
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1091
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +981
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +114
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1590
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +156
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +268
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +314
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +204
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +245    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +130
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +98
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +509
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32()
>   +566    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +237
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +913
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String
>   createDatabaseScript) +117
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection
>   connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection
>   storeItemCollection) +211
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection
>   connection) +134
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +174
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +116
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext
>   internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
>   +121    System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +292
>   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context) +187
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action
>   action) +71
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
>   +482    System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +174
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1
>   action) +273
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +38
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +21    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +69
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +46
>
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues) +19
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__6c.MoveNext()
>   +198    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +48    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<b__1>d__4.MoveNext()
>   +828    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +2534    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +823    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +333
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +450    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +450    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +450    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext()
>   +203    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +62
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext()
>   +193    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +119
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +365    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134

Comment: Is it a DI problem and you aren't closing connection pool objects after each request?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following...

Edit the ApplicationHost.config usually found in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and change setProfileEnvironment to true.

```
<applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
    <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</applicationPoolDefaults>
```

Comment: Thanks your reply. I don't have this file, I am running it from IIS Express (Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. These 3 lines in Startup.cs.

I have commented them out and now it works accordingly.

```
// Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```